# printing whole line with file io

Tags: c, file

This is a part of my 'Phonebook' program.

```
void viewall(){
    int n, checking = 0;
    char name[50];

    fp = fopen("Phonebook.txt","r");
    printf ("\n\n");

    fscanf (fp, "%s %d", name, &n);
    while (!feof(fp)){
        printf (" %s +880%d\n", name, n);
        fscanf (fp, "%s %d", name, &n);
        ++checking;
    }

    if (checking == 0){
        printf (" Contact List is Empty. No Contacts to Show...");
    }

    printf ("\n\n");
    fclose(fp);

    menu();
}
```

This part displays all the contacts in list. But if any contact name has two parts they get separated. For example: I enter Anik Shahriar as name and then enter my number. I looked at my file and this data was there how it should be.

```
Anik Shahriar 01*******93
```

But when I wanted to display all the contacts. It got printed like this:

```
Anik 0
Shahriar 01*******93
```

How can i make the program print the whole line ?

Comment: when you say `fscanf(fp, "%s %d", name, &n)` you're program finds `Anik` which is a string then sees a space and looks for a number and doesn't find it ("Shahriar" is a string), so it puts `0` in `n`. __Then__ it finds "Shahriar" and the phone number, that parts right. In conclusion, you can't use a space  to separate the first and last name unless you have a variable for the first and last name.

Comment: It worked @user3121023 But another problem. This time the name is printed in the same line but contact number is printed in the next line.

Comment: It didn't before. They were on the same line. After using fgets they are in seperate line. How do i terminate '\n' from fgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by the lines

```
fscanf (fp, "%s %d", name, &n);
```

The format identifier %s scans for a single string. Any whitespace character ends the scan.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

> %s
>   String of characters
>   Any number of non-whitespace characters,
>   stopping at the first whitespace character found. A terminating null
>   character is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

I suggest to use ca CSV file and use a format string like.

```
scanf("%[^,] %d", name, number)
```

Dont forget to test the scanf result value.

Comment: Because I am a pedant - it seems funny that you link to a `c++` website to answer a `c` question ;)